# Application.xml file of weblogic in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, xml, jboss

I am using windup tools to migrate applications from weblogic to JBoss. Windup report says changes are needed in the application.xml file (weblogic) shown below. If so, what are necessary changes I should make to make it compatible to JBoss? Please help me here.

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
    <application>
        <display-name>nabs-adaptor-app</display-name>
        <module>
            <ejb>nabs-adaptor-ejb-1_28_1.jar</ejb>
        </module>
        <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>nabs-adaptor-war-1_28_1.war</web-uri>
                <context-root>/nabs-adaptor-war</context-root>
            </web>
        </module>
        <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>APP-INF/lib/PlatformServices-2008.09.26.war</web-uri>
                <context-root>Krump_PlatformServices</context-root>
            </web>
        </module>
    </application>
```

Comment: Which Windup version did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
    version="6">
    <display-name>nabs-adaptor-app</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>nabs-adaptor-ejb-1_28_1.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>nabs-adaptor-war-1_28_1.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>nabs-adaptor-war</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>PlatformServices-2008.09.26.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>Krump_PlatformServices</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Note that I moved your war from APP-INF/lib to the root of the ear (jboss doesn't use APP-INF). Also, I declared a lib folder where you can place your shared jars.